# too many arithmetic instruction slots

Tags: assembly, directx, hlsl

I'm trying to simplify my HLSL so it will be able to complie using ps_2_0.  At this point I'm getting the "Compiled shader code uses too many arithmetic instruction slots (78). Max allowed by the target (ps_2_0) is 64."  Is there a way to force the compiler to produce the assembly code listing file so I can study it?

Comment: It is possible, compile with /Fc “name of output assembly file“

Comment: If it is failing to compile then probably not, if it compiles but is just unhappy then you can or you can also disassemble the object.

Answer (score 0):

[RenderMonkey](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/legacy-cpu-gpu-tools/rendermonkey-toolsuite/) is a bit dated but I always used it to develop test and debug the shaders I write. With this IDE-like environment you can also view the disassembled code, using various geometries and apply textures, all in a visual way.